# Inline Column Width not working with DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have been trying to scratch my head with Jquery DataTables and trying to fix the width of the column headers with inline css.
But Whenever the page loads, datatable auto adjust the width and give equal width to the headers.
I have tried configurable option of datatables.

```
autoWidth:false
column.adjust()
```

and anything that i could find on google.
But still no luck.
Is there a way to give width to headers overriding the default auto adjust of DataTables.
Below is my options:

```
$('#example3').DataTable( {
    scrollY: '450px',
    scrollX: true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    'ordering': false,
    paging: false,
    autoWidth: false
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give width like this also

```
<table class="nowrap table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="50%">ID</th>
            <th width="50%">Created</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

but make sure you need to divide all the th by 100 where 100% width

Or with data-tables Set the first column's width to 20% with

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columns": [
    { "width": "20%" },
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
  ]
} );
```

For more details visit:-[columns width](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "width": "20%", "targets": 0 }
  ]
} );
```

This is the syntax of setting column width for specific column in jquery datatable.

Here target property is the index value of the column ie, the first column has 0 second column ha 1 like that.

For more info gothrough the jQuery datatable [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width)

Answer (score 0):

You can give width like this also

```
columns: [        
    { "width": "50px", title: "Date" },
    { "width": "120px", title: "Client" },  
    { "width": "120px", title: "Project" },
],
```